# Could not resolve dependencies for project org.alfresco:alfresco-transformer-base:jar:2.3.5-SNAPSHOT:

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, alfresco

I have cloned the below alfresco project, have been trying to compile the application, however, I am getting the below errors. I have downloaded the maven on my mac.

Any Solutions?

https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-transform-core

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.342 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-17T14:36:10+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project alfresco-transformer-base: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.alfresco:alfresco-transformer-base:jar:2.3.5-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.alfresco:alfresco-transform-model:jar:1.0.2.11 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project alfresco-transformer-base: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.alfresco:alfresco-transformer-base:jar:2.3.5-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.alfresco:alfresco-transform-model:jar:1.0.2.11 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
```

Below is my pom.xml file that i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-transform-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <image.tag>latest</image.tag>
        <dependency.pdfbox.version>2.0.19</dependency.pdfbox.version>
        <dependency.alfresco-jodconverter-core.version>3.0.1.1</dependency.alfresco-jodconverter-core.version>
        <env.project_version>${project.version}</env.project_version>
        <dependency.alfresco-transform-model.version>1.0.2.11</dependency.alfresco-transform-model.version>
        <dependency.activemq.version>5.15.9</dependency.activemq.version>
        <dependency.jackson.version>2.10.3</dependency.jackson.version>
        <dependency.cxf.version>3.3.5</dependency.cxf.version>
        <dependency.tika.version>1.24.1</dependency.tika.version>
        <dependency.poi.version>4.1.2</dependency.poi.version>
        <dependency.ooxml-schemas.version>1.4</dependency.ooxml-schemas.version>

        <parent.core.deploy.skip>false</parent.core.deploy.skip>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

This alfresco dependency is not available on https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.
Check this link https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/alfresco/

```
<groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
<artifactId>alfresco-transform-core</artifactId>
<version>2.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Update :

You need to add these dependencies manually in your repo files to get it work
PS: alfresco-transform-core last available version is 2.3.4 https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/alfresco/alfresco-transform-core/2.3.4/
https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/alfresco/alfresco-transform-model/1.0.2.11/

Comment: Are there any similar dependencies. that I can use from the link you have provided?

Comment: The last version available is 2.3.4, you can download the dependency from alfresco repo https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/alfresco/alfresco-transform-core/2.3.4/ and put it under your repo files manually so it can be recognized.

Comment: Thank You :) but I still have the same issue with the dependency error